# convert hashtag into url

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem with converting hashtag into url link, i have this code

```
$string = "hi i don't #care about this #هاش";
$text = preg_replace('/(\#)([^\s]+)/', ' <a href="'.SITE_URL.'/tag/$2">#$2</a> ', $string);
echo $text;
```

it work fine with both language Arabic and English but when i have a comma on my string it's give me something like this

[image]

i tried this code also

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', '<a href="/hashtag/$1">#$1</a>', $string);
```

and it's work fine only on English hash

[image]

so how can i fix this

Comment: post you string with `,` comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to permit `&` in front of the hashtags. Doing this wouldn't allow to detect something like `&#39;`.

```
(?<!&)(\#)([^\s]+)
```

Notice the prefix `(?<!&)`, which is a negative lookbehind.